# Installing PDF-Tools Windows(non-geek tutorial)

Tags: pdf-tools

I want to use pdf-tools to anotate pdf files using `org-mode` or viewing pdf outputs of my tex files which I hope it wil support `syntex`. I am following the official help to build for windows. I want to comprehensively tell my situation before and after the steps I've taken.

1. I have `cygwin`, `Imagemagick`, `git` before being introduced to pdf-tools
2. Emacs: I have a windows built not a cygwin built. I downloaded the
   200 MB version of emacs 26.

Now following what Official help requires:

*If using the GNU binaries for Windows, support for PNG and zlib must first be installed by copying the appropriate dlls into emacs’ bin/ directory. Most third-party binaries come with this already done.*

I check the `bin` folder of emacs and these files were there: `zlib.dll`, `libjpeg-8.dll`, `libpng16-16.dll`. I tested to see if I can open PNG or JPEG files in emacs and I could.
Then I installed msys2.
Then I clicked start button typed msys and chose `MSYS2 MinGW 64bit`.
Then I followed all the steps below:

> ```
> $ pacman -Syu
> $ pacman -S base-devel  
> $ pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain  
> $ pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-zlib
> $ pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-libpng
> $ pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-poppler
> $ pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-imagemagick
> ```

For this step *Install PDF tools in Emacs, but do not try to compile the server. Instead, get a separate copy of the source somewhere else.* I went to Emacs folder and right-click on `lib` folder and clicked `GITBash here`, and then entered `git clone https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools` and this created a folder named PDF-Tools in lib folder with the size about 4MB.
I don't know how to effect the next two steps, i.e.:

> Open mingw64 shell (Note: **You must use mingw64.exe and not msys2.exe**)
>
> Compile pdf-tools `$ cd /path/to/pdf-tools $ make -s`

I don't know where my `mingw64.exe` is located. Would you please help me.
Thanks in advance.

**P.S.** I tried this command `make install-server-deps` on `cygwin` and also `MSYS2 MinGW 64bit` but both of them returned this: `-bash: make: command not found`.

Answer (score 1):

It's in your msys64 folder (default: `c:/msys64/`).  Put the bin directory of mingw64 in user path. Delete what you have in lib and then install pdf-tools Options/manage Emacs packages. Close Emacs. Reopen and activate package: `M-x pdf-tools-install RET`. This worked for me. Building the PDF Tools server succeeded :)